# Passing the URL of a page to a PHP POST call

Tags: php, jquery, url, post

I need to pass the URL of a page to a PHP POST function which will return a document. I was wondering if it is possible to pass in the URL via a function or will it have to be stored in a variable? Or is it even possible to do this? I have this function to retrieve the URL of the previous page:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var referrer = document.referrer;
    });
```

And this is the PHP POST method which does not work:

```
    $_POST['http://<THE URL I AM SENDING THE REQUEST TO>&url=<THE URL OF THE PREVIOUS PAGE>'];
```

I had it set up like:

```
    $_POST['http://<THE URL I AM SENDING THE REQUEST TO>&url=referrer'];
```

But it would not run. Does anyone know how I can get this to work? Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a form? If so make a hidden input with the value set to the URL in question.

Comment: If its a GET method why do you use $_POST?

Comment: Sorry it is POST I edited the question there